# OutputDebugString / System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine and Debugger.IsAttached

Tags: c#

I need to check if OutputDebugString / System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine's output will go to never never land.

Seems like OutputDebugString is a native method while System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine is writing to internal trace listeners.

Is Debugger.IsAttached a sufficient check for this?

Debugger.IsAttached doesn't seem to pick up if something like DebugView is running. I need to be able to check if ANYTHING will see output from OutputDebugString / System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine.

Comment: May I ask why you need to check for this?

Comment: What's your case? A performance gain from not generating the output if a debugger isn't attached? That's a little outside the purview of `OutputDebugString`. For trace listeners, you can use `TraceSwitch` to prevent generating anything if nobody cares.

Comment: @JeroenMostert -- Exactly. Diagnostic information in my app can be "expensive" to generate. If nothing is listening to the output, I want to skip generating it. I don't want to use app.config or a registry key. I want to do it based on an internal bool for max performance. i don't want to rely on TraceSwitch either since that requires app.config stuff and this is a shared lib... I want to handle it automatically.

Comment: @Amy, see my answer to Jeroen for more info.

Comment: Are you at all interested in someone attaching "later"? The absolute fastest way of not generating the info is by checking a `static readonly bool` since the JIT will be able to optimize the whole code away at runtime, with the significant drawback that there's no way to turn the logging back on while the application runs.

Comment: If your question is if there's one global, glorious, accepted way of signaling that somebody is listening to debug information -- no, there's not. `OutputDebugString` has nothing (as far as I know), tracing has switches, frameworks like log4net have log levels, ETW has... whatever ETW has, it's really unfriendly. `Debugger.IsAttached` isn't very convenient because, as you've noticed, this really *only* works if a debugger is attached, and there are plenty of scenarios where you might want diagnostics without debugging.

Comment: @JeroenMostert -- Yes, I am interested if somebody attaches later :). I am aware of logging frameworks, this is for a sort of internal framework, so I am only really concerned about OutputDebugString / System.Diagnostics output. The key being that I want to do it automatically, not require the consumer to change anything.

Comment: For `Debug.WriteLine()` you can check [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners.Count > 0`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners(v=vs.110).aspx).  Is that what you want?

Comment: @dbc, testing in a console app, it seems like there is always an instance of DefaultTraceListener whether the debugger or dbgview is running.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I think debugview problem does a Win32 hook. So no way to detect that other then to check for the process running I guess.

Comment: Yes, but you can remove it.  Debug output goes to the console or to Visual Studio's output window if you don't.  Actually, maybe I don't know what you mean by *go to never never land.*  Does printing to the console count?

Comment: Is `Debugger.IsAttached` *faster* than output trace information?  What about the race condition (i.e. a debugger isn't attached at the call to `IsAttached` but is on the call to `OutputDebugString`, or a debugger is attached at `IsAttached` but detached before the call to `OutputDebugString`).  Unless you've measured huge performance problems when debuggers aren't attached, this seems like premature optimization.

Comment: @dbc - "never never land" = no op, its thrown away :). i think Pawels answer will do the trick... am testing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to get your hands dirty and use some native stuff you can achieve this. You'll need to use P/Invoke.

`OutputDebugString`, as you can read [here](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html), is based on 4 kernel objects. `Mutex` named `DBWinMutex`, a shared memory `DBWIN_BUFFER` and two events (`DBWIN_BUFFER_READY` and `DBWIN_DATA_READY`) as they wrote in the article - we can't relay on the mutex as it exists all the time. But we could check if the shared section is created.

If we import [`OpenFileMapping`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/OpenFileMapping.html) to our project from pinvoke.net

```
static class NativeFunctions
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr OpenFileMapping(
        uint dwDesiredAccess, 
        bool bInheritHandle,
        string lpName);
}
```

Then we can check if the section is created or not and based on that decide whether something is listening.

Writing this simple program

```
public const int FILE_MAP_READ = 0x0004;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (NativeFunctions.OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, false, "DBWIN_BUFFER") != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Log("Someone is listening");
    }
    else
    {
        Log("I am here alone");
    }
}

private static void Log(string log)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(log);
    Console.WriteLine(log);
}
```

When running without [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview) we get "I'm here alone"

[image]

and with the tool

[image]

Additionally to clarify the things ".. while System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine is writing to internal trace listeners." `Debug.WriteLine` will also write to the same place as `OutputDebugString` but only if VS is not attached - otherwise VS will capture the log and post to its Output window.

Comment: Very cool Pawel! I'll have to test the performance :), might be more expensive to do the isDebuggerAttached and this check then to run the actual code :), but it does detect debugview.

Comment: Hmm.. unfortunately, this check is very expensive. 1100ms for 100k checks vs. just 10ms for Debugger.IsAttached :(... I read the article you linked and had another thought that I'm trying... watch the DBWIN_BUFFER_READY event and wait for it to be signaled. That way it'll be a blocking thing...

Comment: It might be the case. PInvoke is slow on .NET. Remember that `Debugger.IsAttached` is true only when Debugger is attached and it will not detect DebugView. Use what you need for your task. I was happy to research this topic even to extend my knowledge.

Comment: I guess the only solution is to wait for DBWIN_BUFFER_READY to be signaled (listener started) then loop wait with a short sleep on DBWIN_BUFFER (listener stopped). Ugly. i couldn't find any other method to block til the listener stops.

Comment: You are leaking handles. Each `OpenFileMapping` leaves one handle open. Every check consumes a chunk of process' paged pool. Also, if you do not close the handle, the mapping will stay around, *even if WinDbg is closed*! You must call ::CloseHandle() if the call succeeds. @SledgeHammer, you are right, opening a file mapping is not an inexpensive operation. The article says events are not created until the listener attaches, you might use this fact. Opening an event is significantly faster (not *fast*, just faster). And, of course, you understand the whole thing is one big undocumented hack.